# Does an SDN Controller need to be connected to every OpenFlow enabled Switch directly?

Tags: sdn, openflow

Is it possible that the network would still function if the SDN Controller was only connected to one OpenFlow Switch and every other OpenFlow switch would be connected to that switch someway?

And if they need to be directly connected, since there would be lack of physical ports for that much connection, is it possible to use a regular switch in between the controller and other OpenFlow switches?